# What happened to Fang the Boarhound after the Battle of Hogwarts? Did he survive?

Tags: harry-potter

Many people say that he did. But there is a contradictory statement from the book. The book describes that a lone dog the size of a boat lay near the stone steps to the castle when Harry entered it (after witnessing Snape die). Does this mean that the dog lay dead or was it resting? Was it Fang or some other dog?

Comment: You've misread that sentence. It says "A lone **clog**, the size of a small boat, lay abandoned in front of them." A clog being a type of shoe, worn (based on the size) by one of the giants involved in the battle.

Comment: Could hagrid have worn the Clog  ?

Comment: No. Hagrid is never seen wearing clogs, and the very next sentence is "There was no other sign of Grawp or of his attacker." Grawp had last been seen fighting another giant.

Comment: If Fang had died the Death Eaters would have had one seriously pissed half-giant to deal with.

Answer (score 8):

#### Unknown

We don't know what happened to Fang after the Battle of Hogwarts, because the last time Fang is mentioned is *during* the battle:

> "It's all righ', Fang — it's all righ'!" yelled Hagrid, but the great boarhound had taken flight as slivers of china flew like shrapnel through the air, and Hagrid pounded off after the terrified dog, leaving Harry alone.
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter Thirty-One - *The Battle of Hogwarts*</sub>

The lack of explicit mention of him dying is likely why people assume he survived.