# What happened to Hagrid after Battle of Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid

Since it is not specified, what exactly did Hagrid do after Battle of Hogwarts?

Comment: I can't believe this isn't a duplicate. Related but not a dupe: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/232936/what-happened-to-fang-the-boarhound-after-the-battle-of-hogwarts-did-he-survive

Comment: we know he didn't get married at least: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45782/did-jkr-ever-allude-to-what-happened-to-the-relationship-between-hagrid-and-mada. - I guess you could take that as a word of God that he survived and could stretch that into a dupe in that "he survived and didn't get married"

Answer (score 50):

It seems apparent from the Epilogue that Hagrid stayed on at Hogwarts and was still there nineteen years later:

> "Bye, Al," said Harry as his son hugged him. "Don't forget Hagrid's invited you to tea next Friday. Don't mess with Peeves. Don't duel anyone till you've learned how. And don't let James wind you up."